# Server is broken after do-release-upgrade from 18 to 19

Tags: networking, upgrade, ssh, network-manager

I had a (headless) server running 18.04LTS. On it ran some standard software: Apache, Docker, SSH, etc.

I ran `do-release-upgrade` and after a seemingly normal set of questions and actions, a reboot was required. After the reboot, I lost all connection to it. Sites didn't load, SSH timed out. Ubuntu 19.10 is installed, but nothing works.

Via the VPS hoster interface I am able to log in from a browser.

### How can I configure my server to be connected to internet (without being connected to internet)

**Basic flow:**

1. I boot, login, `sudo su`
2. `ip a` shows for eth0

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:xx:xx:xx:xx:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

3. `ip link set dev eth0 up` then `ip a s eth0` changes to

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:xx:xx:xx:xx:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xxx/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

4. Adding the network with `ip addr add [my ipv4 address]/22 dev eth0` changes it to

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:xx:xx:xx:xx:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet [my ipv4 address]/22 scope scope eth0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xxx/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

5. `dkpg-reconfigure network-manager` gives `network-manager is broken or not fully installed`. *I tried this because at some point, I regained connectivity via `dkpg-reconfigure network-manager` only to lose it some minor updates and reboots later.*

**Important files**

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# [Contains only comments, no config]
```

/etc/init.d/networking

```
does not exist
```

**Commands unavailable:**

- `dhclient`, `ping`, `netstat`, `ifup`, `ifdown`, `mtr`, `ifconfig`, `arp`, `route`, `ethtool`, `nmcli`

**More things I tried**

- Installing network-manager or dhclient from cache: There are no deb-files in /var/cache/apt/archives. There's still a `lock` file though.
- Trying to see the difference between no connection and not resolving the DNS. I used `echo 1234 | netcat -v 8.8.4.4 80` since `ping` is missing, and got a `Network is unreachable`, so it's not just the DNS.
- Mounting a volume, so I can load missing files that way. Sadly, couldn't `mount` because `nfs-common` isn't installed, it seems.
- Querying the networking service: `Unit networking.service could not be found.`
- Checking the status of `systemd-networkd.service`: it's active and running, but in logs it only reports `eth0: Gained IPv6LL` then `Enumeration completed`. Nothing on IPv4. Will check [that German wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/systemd/networkd/) now.

Comment: Maybe `sudo cat /var/log/apt/term.log` can show you what happened during the upgrade. While `sudo cat /var/log/boot.log` can maybe tell you something about some startup issues. Did you try `sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` after `sudo apt update`? Are your /etc/apt/sources.list entries set correctly? Had a look what `sudo tasksel` tells about installed meta packages?

Comment: Opps. This should have been `sudo dpkg --configure -a` instead of `sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a`

Comment: Currently it seems all interfaces are down, hence no internet, hence no successful installations. Will keep you posted!

Comment: `term.log` shows I removed `network-manager`, after I fixed the connectivity, right before I lost it again, probably as part of removing gnome. I cannot reinstall though without internet. I run on OpenStack so will look into mounting a volume...

Comment: `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install network-manager ` would fix your dependencies issues. But without connection I'm not sure if it gets installed from the archives. But you could try `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/network-manager*.deb`. In this case I'm not sure if the network-manager-gnome also gets installed, but you could complete the line before the* in a way that it won't. You could try `sudo dhclient eth0`, or `nmcli dev status` and `nmcli con up YOURCONNECTION`. The `dhclient` opinion would be used if network-manager is not installed.

Comment: Ah, didn't noticed you've edited and updated your question and that those commands are unavailable. if it's in the archives you maybe can install dhclient with `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/isc-dhcp-client*.deb`.

Comment: What does `sudo systemctl status networking.service` tell you? Are you able to start it? Does `sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd.service` help you somehow? This page is in german language, but maybe worth to read through: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/systemd/networkd/

Comment: Yeah sorry for the edits, I'm still trying hard to debug the issue. Will answer your comments in post!

Comment: Glad it works. It's not that easy to formulate a correct answer for me. Because of the fact you don't use Predictable Network Interface Names - what your question contained, before it has been edited.

Comment: I'll try to formulate an answer later, because of lack of time. I'll post it with guessing you passed the net.ifnames=0 on the kernel command line to use old interface naming.

Comment: Yes, I changed that back and forth a couple of times, hoping it would fix things. I ended up with net.ifnames=0 in grub since that was the way it was before it broke. My guess is it could easily be switched to the other naming method without much effects, just confgure ens3 instead of eth0 everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

The [German wiki from starkus](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/systemd/networkd/) helped me find the solution!

I added a config file in `/etc/systemd/network` containing

```
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
DHCP=yes
Address=[my address]/22
```

It shouldn't work, as another (working) system lacks this file too, but it does, so I'm gonna quickly snapshot it before I do anything else. Everything works, nothing seems broken, my understanding is still minimal, but my relieve is huge.

Thanks for the input, if someone can formulate it in an answer that explains it I can accept that as answer.

*(Now let's hope this time it keeps working)*